# Using onkeydown with JS function to change contenteditable

Tags: javascript

I've seen a few questions on changing contenteditables with JS, but none of them quite make sense to me, so

I have an HTML snippet

```
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" onkeydown="checkEnter()"></div>
```

then I link the JS script at the end of the HTML body

```
<script src='js/jscript.js'></script>
```

and the corresponding JS function is

```
function checkEnter() {
  if (this.keyCode == 13) {
    this.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
  }
}
```

Basically, the user should be able to input text and after pressing enter the text is no longer editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't understand what `this` is.

You need to pass event to the function:

```js
function checkEnter(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13)
    e.target.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);

}
```

```css
#input {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px
}
```

```html
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" onkeydown="checkEnter(event)"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the event object and use it to check the keycode

```js
function checkEnter(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    this.setAttribute("contenteditable", false);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="input" contenteditable="true" onkeydown="checkEnter(event)">
  Here is element
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is bound to global object (window), so you cannot set contenteditable attribute to false for div tag.